# How to access Settings (InspectorControls) in a custom block when using render_callback?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

So I have a custom block that has settings defined in the sidebar like this:

```
<InspectorControls>
        <PanelBody
            title="Call-To-Action Text"
            initialOpen={true}
        >
            <PlainText 
                    label='Text of your Call-To-Action button (optional)'
                    value= { attributes.callToActionText }
                    onChange={ (content) => setAttributes({ callToActionText : content }) }
                />
        </PanelBody>
```

I am using render_callback to do the rendering of the block:

```
function render_my_custom_block($attributes) {
 // my render logic
}
```

When I do var_dump($attributes), I don't see the "callToActionText".

How can I access the settings within this function?

Comment: Have you defined your attributes in the register_block_type function on the php side?

Comment: You must have to define attributes in `registerBlockType` on JS side. The one on PHP side is just a dynamic rendering function and it needs attributes from blocks definition.